# VirtualBox suddenly became slow

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Until a few weeks ago, VirtualBox was working fine without any kind of issues. But recently it became too slow. Earlier, Windows 10 used to be installed in 10 to 20 minutes. Now  it takes almost 10 minutes to bring up the installation window. Even my Genymotion VMs stopped booting (although Android AVD is working fine). I really don't know what happened. I don't want to reinstall Windows. Here's what I tried so far:-

Removed All VMs and reinstalled VirtualBox.

Tried uninstalling/reinstalling Hyper-V.

Updated Windows 10 to latest build (20H2 to 21H2).

I am using a Laptop with the following configurations:-

```
Intel i5 7300HQ
16 GB RAM
1TB Crusial CT1000MX SATA SDD
Windows 10 Pro 21H2
Oracle VirtualBox 6.1.34
```

logs:- [VBox.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12bnqsSa3h-3pU0K-jNajLHfIdTfxg6EG/view?usp=sharing) [VBoxHardening.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lat5UK-rtDljewerimui4_znMm0Gz3iY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'd love to see someone answer this, but all you've done is provide information. You didn't ask an actual question. Please ask a question and let's see if that make your post show up better.